# Using sql to fetch account balance for each owner

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of owners

```
id | owner
--------
1  | Jack
2  | Lee
3  | Daniel
```

and a table of their transactions

```
id | owner_id | change
----------------
1  | 1  | 500
2  | 2  | 300
3  | 1  | -100
4  | 2  | 100
5  | 2  | -300
```

and I'm trying to get the balance of Jack's account. So for example here I would return

```
500
400
```

as Jack will first have 500 as his balance and after the change he will have 400.

What I currently have is

```sql
SELECT O.id, change FROM Owners O, Transactions WHERE O.id = 1 & Transactions.owner_id = 1;
```

but I can only get the rows of Jack's change. What can I do to get the balance for each row?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(change_v) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS balance
FROM transactions 
WHERE owner_id = 1
```

An alternative could be to use a variable, like this:

```
SET @balance := 0;
SELECT (@balance := @balance + change_v) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE owner_id = 1 
ORDER BY id
```

Keep in mind that `change` is a reserved word in MySQL, that's why I simply used the name `change_v`. There are ways you can use reserved words for column names, but I wouldn't advise you to do so.